# how do you get the title of the active window using autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I tried to use

```
winget, title, ID
msgbox %title%
```

but the message box comes up blank.
what am I missing here ?

Comment: Do you really mean `topmost` and not `active`?

Comment: Yes, I meant active by saying topmost...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted the window on the *bottom* you could utilize `winactivatebottom` but since you want the top one, you are going to have to loop through the windows, I think.  This little snippet will give you the windows, and the index should be their order, I think.

Take a look at this snippet I [fetched from here](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/4408-activate-topmost-window/).

```
F2:: 
    WinGet, WindowList, List 
    ToolTip
    List =

    Loop %WindowList% 
    { 
    WinUID := WindowList%A_Index% 
    WinGetTitle, WinTitle, ahk_id %WinUID% 
    List = %List%Window %A_Index% of %WindowList%`n%WinTitle%`n%WinUID%`n`n
    }
    ToolTip  %List%
Return
```

However, if you don't need the `topmost` window, but only the `active` window, then you are in luck!  Just use `wingetactivetitle` (straight from a simple search through the documenation's index.  The docs are your friends!)

```
WinGetActiveTitle, TheTitle
```

Comment: okay, I see this code segment working. But I really do not need the whole 9 yards. I just need the title of the active window. I tried to substitute variables, in a way that it made sense to me but I don't get my simple 2 line code (or it may be 3 or 5 lines) working.

Comment: Great!  Easy solution.